# Datepicker options on HTML instead of javascript

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Is there a way to provide `datepicker-options` in [ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in the HTML instead of creating a separate object for each datepicker?

The original documentation says

> to configure the uib-datepicker you need to create an object in
>   Javascript with all the options and use it on the datepicker-options
>   attribute

However, I have almost 40 different datepickers on a page. And I have to provide min and max dates dynamically.

Earlier versions (*ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js*) of datepicker, I could use max-date or min-date attribute with some ng-model value on the input element itself. Now do I have to create a JS object for each datepicker-options? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you can write the options inline, on the html iteself

Comment: sometimes your brain stops working like it is supposed to. thanks svarog. (y)

Comment: only sometimes? you're a lucky guy!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments by @savrog, I just added the date-picker options in HTML as follows:

```
<input datepicker-options="{minDate: MyMinDate}" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="vm.dDischargeDateFormatted" is-open="dDischargeDateFormatted" ng-required="false" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"/>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dDischargeDateFormatted=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
```